# How get details on Firewall IP address

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to check firewall IP address, port number, subnet mask using PowerShell command?

I tried search, however, got only Primary IP instead

Comment: Please read the help [about asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Then edit the question and add more details. For example, naming the firewall product and showing how you get the IP would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get back what you ask for. So, you need to know how to ask the target for it.

A firewall device is nothing but a regular computer, even if it is purpose built. So, if you can reach it, just use the PowerShell network, network adapters, connection and firewall cmdlets to get information about it. That is if the FW you are trying to reach supports it.

There are several examples for you to use in the PowerShell built-in help files. So, you should find all the examples you need here:

```
Get-Help -Name Get-NetIPConfiguration -Examples
Get-Help -Name Get-NetAdapter -Examples
Get-Help -Name Get-NetIPAddress -Examples
Get-Help -Name Get-NetIPInterface -Examples
```

That first one will give you virtually all you are asking for, except for ports.
FW's can have a lot of ports open, so, you need to just do a port scan on it to see which ones are open. That is what the cmdlet below is for.

```
Get-Help -Name Test-NetConnection -Examples
```

Just pipe in a list of ports using a for loop.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first one - Get-NetIPConfiguration before posting this question in this forum. However, this command gives out some IP4address, DNSserver etc how to know which is firewall IP ?

Comment: It wouldn't be much help, were the FW be reached via routing. In larger networks this is common a scenario.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more info as @vonPryz is directing. Is this just a Windows server, Linux server or some purposed built 3rdP hardware unit. Cisco, CheckPoint, etc. The IPA are of course assigned to the network card(s) on a device, it does not matter what that device role is. So, whatever the primary, enabled active NIC IPA is, that is what you are after. Just hit the device using Test-Connection or ping and the device and it will give you the active IPA or look it up in DNS.